# How can I sort my friends activities first and keep good performance?

Tags: sql-server, sqlperformance

The code here below will search in the activity-table for users that match a given name. I want it to return top 10 activities with my friends activities first.

If we populate the Activities table with million of records then we can still use index and make the search for activities very fast. However it gets slow when I want to order the result by friends activities at the top.

Consider when the search from the Activities table returns 1000 rows and then we would need to scan the friends table and match with the 1000 rows from the matching table in Activities.

Do you have any suggestions on how to rewrite or re-model this database / query to make it fast? Or should the problem be solved in a different way?
I am looking for a solution that is consistent in speed even as data grow.

```
declare @Activities as table 
(
    UserId int, ActivityName nvarchar(50), AccountName nvarchar(50), ActivityDate DateTime, Likes int
    INDEX IX NONCLUSTERED (AccountName,ActivityDate,Likes,UserId,ActivityName) 
)
declare @Friends as table 
(
    UserId int, FriendId int
    INDEX IX CLUSTERED (UserId, FriendId)
)

insert into @Activities values (1, 'Activity 1', 'John Doe', '2019-01-01', 10) 
insert into @Activities values (2, 'Activity 2', 'Max Gordon', '2019-02-01', 100)
insert into @Activities values (1, 'Activity 3', 'John Doe', '2019-03-01', 0)
insert into @Activities values (3, 'Activity 4', 'John Roe', '2019-08-01', 40)

insert into @Friends values (1,2) -- John is friend with max
insert into @Friends values (2,1) -- Max is friend with John
insert into @Friends values (1,3) -- John Doe is friend with John Roe

declare @UserId int = 2

select top 10
    a.ActivityName, a.AccountName, a.Likes, case when f.FriendId is null then 0 else 1 end as IsFriend
from 
    @Activities a
    left join @Friends f on f.UserId = @UserId and f.FriendId = a.UserId
where 
    a.AccountName like 'j%'
order by 
    case when f.FriendId is null then 0 else 1 end desc, 
    a.Likes desc,  
    case when a.ActivityDate > getdate() then 0 else 1 end,
    a.ActivityDate
```

Comment: Place ordering on the client side. Usually, such a query is used to fill the datatable object in ADO.NET. Once you have the datatable it is easy to make any kind of sorting.

Comment: "we would need to scan the friends table and match with the 1000 rows from the matching table in Activities." - The RDBMS should do that for you. And efficiently, too, if you have proper indexes.

Comment: Why is the "Account Name" stored in Activities? What's the primary key of Activities?

Comment: "it gets slow when..." - Did you try, or are you just assuming?

Comment: @DarkoMartinovic, While I can agree with you on that sometimes, I don't think it will work in this case. Lets say for example that you are searching for songs in spotify and spotify want to order the songs by songs you previously have listened to. Then when you start typing "b" you don't want all songs that starts with "b" returned to the client.

Comment: @JimmyB, I am quite familiar with indexes and have tried various options without any luck. As I mentioned, this is a simplified description of the problem but it still shows the case. There are proper primary keys on the tables.

I have tried this, the problem is real, it's nothing that I only assume. The code here is code that you can use to reproduce the query plan. But you will probably need to populate it with more data than I have in my sample.

Comment: The `case` expressions may be a bottleneck too. You may want to try to get along without them, e.g. by `COUNT`ing instead.

Comment: Patrik, such situations you mentioned could be handled in .NET code. In that case you should asks more/less records from SQL Server and display then on the client side.You should decide what is cheaper/expensive for you.

Comment: The best solution I have come up with so far is to use outer apply instead. Such as the code below. However It's still not fast enough.
`
select top 10
 a.ActivityName, a.AccountName, a.Likes, case when friend.f is null then 0 else 1 end as IsFriend
from 
 @Activities a
 outer apply (select FriendId f from @Friends where UserId = @UserId and FriendId = a.UserId) friend
where 
 a.AccountName like 'j%'
order by 
 case when friend.f is null then 0 else 1 end desc, 
 a.Likes desc,  
 case when a.ActivityDate > getdate() then 0 else 1 end,
 a.ActivityDate`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT a.*, COUNT(f.*) AS FriendCount
FROM Activities a
LEFT OUTER JOIN Friends f ON f.FriendId = a.UserId AND f.UserId = @UserId
GROUP BY a.*
ORDER BY SIGN(COUNT(f.*)) DESC, a.LIKES DESC, a.ActivityDate DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a correlated subquery can be more effective than Left Join + Case statement

```
select top 10
    a.ActivityName, a.AccountName, a.Likes, IsFriend
from 
    @Activities a
    outer apply (select 1 as isFriend FROM @Friends f WHERE f.UserId = @UserId and f.FriendId = a.UserId) f
where 
    a.AccountName like 'j%'
order by 
    isFriend desc, 
    a.Likes desc,  
    case when a.ActivityDate > getdate() then 0 else 1 end,
    a.ActivityDate
```

Comment: Yes, I tried with outer apply also. It's better but It's still not as fast as needed. Maybe if you exceed an amount of data that it will be slower? I am looking for a solution that is consistent in speed as data grow.